What are classroom examples for the HHL algorithm?
I am teaching a course in QC and one of the topics I would like to put a good emphasis on  HHL algorithm for solving systems of linear equations.
Anyway, besides the theory, I would like to add some nice little demonstrations/examples in class, no coding or simulation, but a neat example or application doable within a classroom setting.
But I do not have any luck finding such an application.
Any help would be very welcome!

Seem to be relevant Qiskit guide to HHL and a pedagogy paper based on HHL.
